# Retain DialogFragment state on orientation change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment which loads info from a file and creates a certain number of EditText fields on the screen (there can be 5-6 minimum, or there can be dozens of them). They all have an initial value when loaded form the file.
The user can also add additional text fields by pressing a button. These text fields can be added in multiple places, in between existing fields. Everything is added programmatically.
When an orientation  change occurs, all this is lost. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Not by saving info and then restoring it, but simply to prevent it from happening at all?

The number of fields at dialog creation depends on the information that will be loaded from the file. The number of fields when an orientation change happens does not have to be the same. New fields could have been added by the user pressing one out of multiple buttons that adds new fields. The dialog can have 30+ fields at one point. Saving state and then restoring it could require a complex method (probably something like saving the views in a static list, or maybe the entire layout). Preventing orientation change entirely while the dialog is open is probably the best option, or maybe forcing it to go landscape since the user will need to type a lot...

Is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: It's strongly encouraged to save and retain state correctly.  If you bypass the activity lifecycle for something as simple as what you're doing, you'll likely introduce other problems into your app at a later stage.  Then you'll wish you had done it correctly the first time.

Comment: What kind of other problems?

Comment: If you handle configuration changes on your own, you will lose the ability to easily do these things (and many more): Have different layouts and other resources for landscape and portrait, respond to changes in language for localization, respond to changes in effective screen size because of external displays (like Chromecast).  If you say you want to handle configuration changes on your own, you need to be absolutely certain your app needs to behave in a way that's not normal for Android apps.  Don't use it as a shortcut to avoid having to do work that makes your app correctly on Android.

Comment: If the saving and restoring process is complex, and if the layout is same in portrait and landscape, we can resort to skip the lifecycle processes, though I agree that in a normal scenario, not doing so is recommended. I believe finally it all boils down to the requirement / use case that the developer is trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add attribute `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"` to the `Activity` declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: It still behaves the same after adding that.

Comment: But keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize works! (I have a phone with physical keyboard)

Comment: Great! Edited the answer for others looking for the solution.

Comment: Note that Adding `android:configChanges = "orientation"` will restrict activity from being recreated when orientation changed.

Answer (score 0):

call `setRetainInstance(true)` on DialogFragment
Also override `onSavedInstance(Bundle)`/`OnViewStateRestored(Bundle)` on Activity in which you've added it.